# Excel Macro to Copy and Paste Format Line by Line instead of range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am using conditional formatting in Excel 2007 to compare values row by row in cells H, K and U.

Since I am trying to use the conditional fomartting row by row instead of a range of cells.
My hand cramped up by row 50, and I have another few hundreds to go.

Is there a macro that would check the rows and paste the format without having to do one at a time?

A million thanks.

Comment: Can you explain that with the help of a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to apply the conditional formatting row-by-row.  If you use the proper combination of relative and absolute references in your conditional formatting formula, you can do it all in one shot.  For example, select A1:C10 and enter this formula for conditional formatting

=$A1=1

Because I made the column absolute with the dollar sign, every cell in A1:C10 will refer to column A.  But since the row is relative, every cell will refer to column A on its same row.  So B8's conditional format formula will be =$A8=1

Comment: Thank you for your input, but in the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager. I need the apply to section to reflect only the 3 cells in H, K and U. When copying the forumula, it would apply to a range of cells and I am trying to avoid that.